# How to send XHR request only to real domains?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm send `XMLHttpRequest` and want to send it only to real domains, which are not null and are not Chrome's internal `chrome:` domains.

Until now i fail on this  - my `XMLHttpRequest` is sending under any circumstances - but in case of `currentDomaon == 0` or `currentProtocoll == "chrome:"` it comes empty.

What i'm doing wrong? How should i adapt the code to get the goal?

```
var currentDomain = "";
var currentProtocol ="";
const processingTabId = {};

function run(tab) {
    if (processingTabId[tab.id]) return;
    processingTabId[tab.id] = true;

    let newUrl = new URL(tab.pendingUrl || tab.url)
    currentDomain = newUrl.hostname;
    currentProtocol = newUrl.protocol;

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var protocol = "https://";
        var middle = ".myservice/"
        var end = "/action/data/";

        xhr.open("GET", protocol + middle + currentDomain + end, true);

        xhr.responseType = 'document';

if (currentDomain !== null) && (currentProtocol !== "chrome:") {
xhr.send();
        }       
}
```

Comment: Why would you be trying to send a request to any of those domains in the first place? In what context will this be used, do you not control where requests are sent?

Comment: if (currentDomain && currentProtocol ==="https:")

Comment: @mplungjan `currentDomain` could be anything - it is domain with subdomain without protocol, `currentProtocol` could be `http:` too

Comment: if (currentDomain) would test null, undefined and empty Then use
`if (currentDomain && currentProtoco.indexOf("http") ===0)`

Comment: @mplungjan then it should be something like `if (currentDomain && currentProtocol === ("https:" || "http:"))` - correct?

Comment: It is extremely unlikely you will find any protocol like httpblala or something. But yeah, your JS is not valid. Try `if (currentDomain && ["http:","https"].includes(currentProtocol))`

Answer (score -2):

You could use a Regular Expression to determine if a string is a valid URL starting with HTTP/HTTPS.

For example:

```
https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url) Stack Overflow post.